# Convert a list of sets to a set of sets (to find the unique elements)

Tags: python, list, set

I want to find the unique elements in `A =[set([1,2]),set([1,2]), set([1])]` in Python. I tried set(A); it didn't work. Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your sets to [`frozenset()` objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset):

```
set(frozenset(s) for s in A)
```

A `frozenset()` is an immutable set object, and more importantly, hashable. Thus it can be stored in a `set()`.

Demo:

```
>>> A = [set([1,2]),set([1,2]), set([1])]
>>> set(frozenset(s) for s in A)
set([frozenset([1, 2]), frozenset([1])])
```